# Is it possible to get mouse buttons 4, 5, etc?

Tags: javascript, mouselistener

Simply put, is there any way to detect additional mouse button presses in JavaScript? It's not documented with the rest of the mouse input, so I guess it's not in standard implementation.

Is there any way, such as a library, which can enable extra mouse buttons?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button

Comment: The working draft of the spec is found at the link below - the mozilla implementation of detecting auxiliary button clicks as described in the link provided by @Briggy should work cross browser.

https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mouseevents

Answer (score 4):

Yes you could do this, check **[MouseEvent.button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button)**, see example below that will detect 3 and 4 buttons click.

> Some pointing devices provide or simulate more buttons. To represent such buttons, the value must be doubled for each successive button (in the binary series 8, 16, 32, ... ) as mentioned in **https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mouseevents**

```js
var whichButton = function (e) {
    // Handle different event models
    var e = e || window.event;
    var btnCode;

    if ('object' === typeof e) {
        btnCode = e.button;

        switch (btnCode) {
            case 3:
                console.log('Browser Back button clicked.');
            break;

            case 4:
                console.log('Browser Forward button clicked.');
            break;

            default:
                console.log('Unexpected code: ' + btnCode);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<button onmouseup="whichButton(event);" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault();">Click with mouse...</button>
```

Comment: To represent such buttons, the value must be doubled for each successive button (in the binary series 8, 16, 32, ... ) check my update.

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually work, for me, using Chrome, IE, Edge, Firefox or Opera.

Comment: As implied by the switch statement's contents, mouse buttons 3 and 4 are already binded to the browser's back and forward actions in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge (and I presume more). I have created [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LqxoMy) to add an `e.preventDefault();` under the `var e` declaration to suppress the binded browser action. I have verified this works in Chrome 71, but unfortunately in both FireFox 65 and Edge 42, `e.preventDefault()` does not suppress the binded browser action. Does anyone know a way to suppress it in all browsers?

Answer (score -1):

```
var whichButton = function (e) {
    // Handle different event models
    var e = e || window.event;
    var btnCode;

    if ('object' === typeof e) {
        btnCode = e.button;

        switch (btnCode) {
            case 3:
                console.log();
            break;

            case 4:
                console.log();
            break;

            default:
                console.log('Unexpected code: ' + btnCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Always include the test to explain your code's logic, otherwise, it may not help other