# Preventing mouse fourth and fifth buttons from navigating back/forward in browsers history?

Tags: javascript

How does one prevent default behavior of mouse fourth and fifth buttons (going back and forward through the browsers history)? I want to use these buttons for camera movement in my browser game.

Comment: Closely related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553357/is-it-possible-to-get-mouse-buttons-4-5-etc

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do this recently for [CubicleSoft File Explorer](https://github.com/cubiclesoft/js-fileexplorer).  To accomplish the task, three new 'popstate's were set up using browser history:  Back, Main, Forward.  Using the hardware back or forward buttons on the mouse triggers the popstate handler, which resets history to the "Main" state.

```
    // Capture browser-level back/forward buttons.  Alters browser history.
    var CapturePopStateHandler = function(e) {
        if (e.state && e.state._fileexplorer)
        {
            if (e.state._fileexplorer === 'back')
            {
                window.history.forward();

            }
            else if (e.state._fileexplorer === 'forward')
            {
                window.history.back();

            }
        }
    };

    // Sets up three history items and places the user in the middle of those three.
    window.history.pushState({ _fileexplorer: 'back' }, document.title);
    window.history.pushState({ _fileexplorer: 'main' }, document.title);
    window.history.pushState({ _fileexplorer: 'forward' }, document.title);
    window.history.back();

    window.addEventListener('popstate', CapturePopStateHandler, true);
```

The downside is that the user is now stuck on the page unless they use the long-press back button option.  But the hardware back/forward hardware mouse buttons are definitely captured (as is the Alt + Left/Right Arrow key combos).  Ideally, the capture state is undone whenever it is no longer needed.